# Rails Routes - Dynamic from Gems - can't modify frozen String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, load, routes, rubygems

I have a Rails app (Rails 3.2.9/Ruby 1.9.3) which consists of several small parts (Once it was one big single app, but i was necessary to split it up into components).

Now I've got several parts of the app, loaded as gems into a main app.

I'm trying to load the routes to the parts of the app dynamically, also i try to prevent URL-Hacking, that's why i would like to create all the available routes dynamically and put the controller#action part into a SHA1 string like that:

```
get   "/#{controller+action as SHA!}/:id", :controller => c_name, :action => ac
```

The whole code in one of my components looks like this (in routes.rb):

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
    BootLog.info "loading -> Smartconcepts#Concept routes"  
    SmartconceptsConcept::SmartconceptsConceptEngine::LOADED_CONTROLLERS.each do |c_name|
      c_controller = c_name.camelize

      c_name = c_name.gsub("_controller", "")


      hex_name = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(c_name)
      real_controller_actions = c_controller.constantize.action_methods

      BootLog.info " -- register: #{c_name} as:     #{hex_name}"
      BootLog.info " --- #{real_controller_actions.size} actions"

      # Default
      get   "/#{hex_name}/:action(.:id)", :controller => c_name
      post  "/#{hex_name}/:action(.:id)", :controller => c_name

      real_controller_actions.each do |ac|

        a_hex_name = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest((ac+c_name))

        BootLog.info " ----  #{c_name}##{ac} as:      #{a_hex_name}"

        get   "/#{a_hex_name}/:id", :controller => c_name, :action => ac
        post  "/#{a_hex_name}/:id", :controller => c_name, :action => ac
      end  


    end 


  end
```

so...

```
SmartconceptsConcept::SmartconceptsConceptEngine::LOADED_CONTROLLERS
```

is loading very fine from my engine, loading the action_methods also works fine.

```
rake routes
```

exactly shows what i expect but when loading pages in browsers I get

```
RuntimeError (can't modify frozen String):
```

which is obviously caused by loading routes the WAY I do?

What can I do to make it work (disable class caching didn't solve it)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's obvious based on what you've posted, but some code is trying to modify a frozen string which is what causing that error. Are you sure it's not a controller/model action/method as part of the render? The console should provide more explicit debugging information to track down the culprit.

Comment: so obviously the code is just doing fine, but loading the line
    real_controller_actions = c_controller.constantize.action_methods

causes the problem. doin same things with static strings works

Comment: I'm not able for figure out where, but in one of the strings you're using you'll need to call the `.dup` method to work with an unfrozen copy of that string. That off-course, is just based on the error message you're getting.

Comment: Actually I think it might be this line: `c_controller = c_name.camelize` to changing it to: `c_controller = c_name.dup.camelize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem where the loaded controller action names.

using .dup finally did it.

```
real_controller_actions = c_controller.constantize.action_methods
#...
real_controller_actions.each do |ac|
    a_hex_name = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest((ac.dup+c_name))
end
```